# How to query data with the GROUP BY keyword within a date

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

Here is the problematic SQL query and the results that it yields:
[image]

What I need, however, is to have the data formatted in the following way:

```
Emp No   Sign In                          Sign out
022195   2013-01-29 09:18:00              2013-01-29 19:18:00  
043770   2013-01-29 10:07:00              2013-01-29 17:07:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the date() function to aggregate the day in MySQL. The trick is to use it in the group by clause.

```
select name, 
   min(date) as Sign_In,
   max(date) as Sign_Out,
from text_based_attendance 
group by date(date), name
order by name
```

This will give a result grouping the employees by their names and the dates that they worked on, showing only the sing in/out times.

Here is my SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/740e2/1

In Orace, you would do the same with the EXTRACT function:

```
   select name, 
   min(mdate) as Sign_In,
   max(mdate) as Sign_Out
   from text_based_attendance
   group by EXTRACT(day from mdate),name
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/96b6c/1

For Postgres, it's more or less the same as in Oracle.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to do any subqueries for that, you can do it with basic [aggregate functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-aggregate.html) over the table and group by name

```
select
     t.name as EmpNo,
     min(t.date) as SignIn,
     max(t.date) as SignOut
from text_based_attendance as t
group by t.name
order by t.name
```

there're no need for alias (`as t`) in this query, but I think it's good practice to add alias to your query so you can easily modify and add joins in the future.

For PostgreSQL, if you want to group by date and get min and max for each date, you can do:

```
select
     t.name as EmpNo,
     t::date as Date,
     min(t.date) as SignIn,
     max(t.date) as SignOut
from text_based_attendance as t
group by t.name, t::date
order by t.name
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've got it right:

```
select name, 
       min(date) as Sign_In,
       max(date) as Sign_Out
from text_based_attendance 
group by name
```

Comment: This does not group "within a date", if I got the question right.